# Stanford NLP NER, Sentiment, SUTime Performance Issue

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition, sutime

The text in the main method seem to be taking more than 2 seconds to return NER. I am not an expert in NLP and this code is not at all scalable. I have added comments in 2 places where the bottleneck i have identified. Can you please suggest improvements to improve the performance of the program.

Thanks.

```
 public class NERSentimentUtil
{
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NERSentimentUtil.class);

private static final String serializedClassifier7 = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
private static final String serializedClassifier4 = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
private static final String serializedClassifier3 = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";

private static NERClassifierCombiner ncc;
private static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

static
{       
    try
    {
        ncc = new NERClassifierCombiner(serializedClassifier3,serializedClassifier4,serializedClassifier7);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(e);
    }
}

static
{               
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment, sutime");
    /*props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");*/

    String defs_sutime = "/edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt";
    String holiday_sutime = "/edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt";
    String _sutime = "/edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt";

    String sutimeRules = defs_sutime + "," + holiday_sutime + "," + _sutime;
    props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "true");
    props.setProperty("-sutime.rules", sutimeRules);
    props.setProperty("sutime.binders", "0");
    props.setProperty("sutime.markTimeRanges", "false");
    props.setProperty("sutime.includeRange", "false");
    props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.sutime", "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "20");
    //props.setProperty("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "false");
    //props.setProperty("nthreads", "16");
    //props.setProperty("threads", "16");
    //props.setProperty("parse.nthreads","16");
    //props.setProperty("ssplit.eolonly","true");

    props.setProperty("-parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    RedwoodConfiguration.current().clear().apply();
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    //RedwoodConfiguration.empty().capture(System.err).apply();
}

//A sentiment score of 0 or 1 is negative, 2 neutral and 3 or 4 positive.
private static int getScore(int score)
{
    if(score<2)
        return -1;
    else if(score==2)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;       
}

public static HashMap<String,Object> getStanford(String s, long dateString)//"2013-07-14"
{   
    int finalScore =0;

    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> dateMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> dateCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, String> dateSentenceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> personMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> personCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> orgMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> orgCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    HashMap<String, Integer> locationMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> locationCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    HashMap<String, Article_Location> locationArticleMap = new HashMap<String, Article_Location>();

    ArrayList<Articel_Ner> organisationlist = new ArrayList<Articel_Ner>();
    ArrayList<Articel_Ner> personlist = new ArrayList<Articel_Ner>();
    ArrayList<Artilcle_Ner_Date> datelist = new ArrayList<Artilcle_Ner_Date>();
    ArrayList<Article_NerLocation> locationList = new ArrayList<Article_NerLocation>();     

    try
    {
        Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(s);//1/3 rd time is taken up by this line

        List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
        {
             String str = sentence.toString();

             int score = getSentiment(sentence);

             finalScore+=score;
             boolean dFlag = true;

             List<Triple<String,Integer,Integer>> triples = ncc.classifyToCharacterOffsets(str);

             for (Triple<String,Integer,Integer> trip : triples)
             {
                 String ne = trip.first();
                 String word = str.substring(trip.second(), trip.third).toLowerCase();

                 switch(ne)
                 {
                    case "LOCATION":                        
                        extractLocation(locationMap, locationCountMap, locationArticleMap, score, word);
                        break;

                    case "ORGANIZATION":                        
                        extractOrg(orgMap, orgCountMap, score, word);                       
                        break;

                    case "PERSON":                      
                        extractPerson(personMap, personCountMap, score, word);
                        break;

                    case "DATE":
                        if(dFlag)
                        {
                         extractSUDate(dateString, dateMap, dateCountMap, dateSentenceMap, str, score);
                         dFlag = false;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                 }
             }
        }
            //2/3rd of the time taken by these 4 methods:: can be obtimized
        mapDate(dateMap, dateCountMap, dateSentenceMap, datelist);
        mapLocation(locationMap, locationCountMap, locationArticleMap, locationList);   
        mapOrg(orgMap, orgCountMap, organisationlist);  
        mapPerson(personMap, personCountMap, personlist);
        //
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error(e);
        logger.error(s);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(finalScore>0)
        finalScore = 1;
    else if(finalScore<0)
        finalScore = -1;
    else
        finalScore = 0;

    map.put("ORGANISATION", organisationlist);
    map.put("PERSON", personlist);
    map.put("DATE", datelist);
    map.put("LOCATION", locationList);
    map.put("SENTIMENT", finalScore);

    return map;
}

private static void extractPerson(HashMap<String, Integer> personMap, HashMap<String, Integer> personCountMap,
        int score, String word)
{       
    if(personMap.get(word)!=null)
    {
        personMap.put(word, personMap.get(word)+score);
        personCountMap.put(word, personCountMap.get(word)+1);
    }
    else
    {
        personMap.put(word, score);
        personCountMap.put(word, 1);
        //personSentenceMap.put(pname, str);
    }   
}

private static void extractOrg(HashMap<String, Integer> orgMap, HashMap<String, Integer> orgCountMap,
        int score, String word)
{
    if(orgMap.get(word)!=null)
    {
        orgMap.put(word, orgMap.get(word)+score);
        orgCountMap.put(word, orgCountMap.get(word)+1);                             
    }
    else
    {
        orgMap.put(word, score);
        orgCountMap.put(word, 1);
        //orgSentenceMap.put(oname, str);
    }
}

private static void extractLocation(HashMap<String, Integer> locationMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> locationCountMap,
        HashMap<String, Article_Location> locationArticleMap,
        int score,
        String word)
{
    if(locationMap.get(word)!=null)
    {
        locationMap.put(word, locationMap.get(word)+score);
        locationCountMap.put(word, locationCountMap.get(word)+1);                               
    }
    else
    {
        Article_Location articleLocation = LocationUtil.getLocation(word);

        locationMap.put(word, score);
        locationCountMap.put(word, 1);
        locationArticleMap.put(word, articleLocation);
    }   
}

private static void extractSUDate(long dateString,
        HashMap<String, Integer> dateMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> dateCountMap,
        HashMap<String, String> dateSentenceMap, 
        String str,
        int score) {

    Annotation dateAnnotation = new Annotation(str);
    dateAnnotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, FormatUtil.getDate(dateString));
    pipeline.annotate(dateAnnotation);

    for(CoreMap timex:dateAnnotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class))
    {
        TimeExpression timeExpression = timex.get(TimeExpression.Annotation.class);

         if(timeExpression!=null && timeExpression.getTemporal()!=null &&
            timeExpression.getTemporal().getTimexValue()!=null)
         {           
             String word = checkDate(timeExpression.getTemporal().getTimexValue());

             if(word!=null)
             {
                 if(dateMap.get(word)!=null)
                 {
                     dateMap.put(word, dateMap.get(word)+score);
                     dateCountMap.put(word, dateCountMap.get(word)+1);
                     dateSentenceMap.put(word, dateSentenceMap.get(word)+" "+str);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     dateMap.put(word, score);
                     dateCountMap.put(word, 1);
                     dateSentenceMap.put(word, str);
                 }                       
             }
         }
    }
}

private static int getSentiment(CoreMap sentence) {
    Tree annotatedTree = sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
     int localScore = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(annotatedTree);
     int score = getScore(localScore);       
    return score;
}   


private static void mapLocation(HashMap<String, Integer> locationMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> locationCountMap,
        HashMap<String, Article_Location> locationArticleMap,
        ArrayList<Article_NerLocation> locationList)
{       
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : locationMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        Article_Location articleLocation = locationArticleMap.get(key);

        Article_NerLocation l1 = new Article_NerLocation();
        if(value>=1)
            l1.setNerSentiment(1);
        else if(value<=-1)
            l1.setNerSentiment(-1);
        else
            l1.setNerSentiment(0);            

        l1.setKeyword(key);
        l1.setCount(locationCountMap.get(key));

        if(articleLocation!=null)
        {                   
            l1.setNerCountry(articleLocation.getCountryCode());
            l1.setNerLatLong(articleLocation.getLatitude()+","+articleLocation.getLongitude());
            l1.setTimeZone(articleLocation.getTimeZone());
            l1.setCountryName(articleLocation.getCountryName());
        }

        locationList.add(l1);
    }
}

private static void mapDate(HashMap<String, Integer> dateMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> dateCountMap,
        HashMap<String, String> dateSentenceMap,
        ArrayList<Artilcle_Ner_Date> datelist)
{               
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : dateMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        Artilcle_Ner_Date d1 = new Artilcle_Ner_Date();

        if(value>=1)
            d1.setNerSentiment(1);
        else if(value<=-1)
            d1.setNerSentiment(-1);
        else
            d1.setNerSentiment(0);

        d1.setKeyword(key);
        d1.setCount(dateCountMap.get(key));
        d1.setSentence(dateSentenceMap.get(key));
        d1.setNerDateTheme1(SummaryThemeUtil.getSTByDate(dateSentenceMap.get(key)));
        datelist.add(d1);
    }   
}   

private static void mapOrg(HashMap<String, Integer> orgMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> orgCountMap,
        ArrayList<Articel_Ner> organisationlist) 
{
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : orgMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        Articel_Ner o1 = new Articel_Ner();
        if(value>=1)
            o1.setNerSentiment(1);
        else if(value<=-1)
            o1.setNerSentiment(-1); 
        else
            o1.setNerSentiment(0);            


        o1.setKeyword(key);
        o1.setCount(orgCountMap.get(key));
        organisationlist.add(o1);            
    }       
}

private static void mapPerson(HashMap<String, Integer> personMap,
        HashMap<String, Integer> personCountMap,
        ArrayList<Articel_Ner> personlist)
{
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : personMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        Articel_Ner p1 = new Articel_Ner();
        if(value>=1)
            p1.setNerSentiment(1);
        else if(value<=-1)
            p1.setNerSentiment(-1);
        else
            p1.setNerSentiment(0);            

        p1.setKeyword(key);
        p1.setCount(personCountMap.get(key));
        personlist.add(p1);      
    }
}   

private static String checkDate(String date)
{               
    if(date.length()<10)
        return null;
    else if(date.length()>10)
        date = date.substring(0,10);

    if (date.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"))
        return date; 
    else
        return null;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String text = "Lets meet on every 2nd week. Night is young. Happy new Year. The festival will be held on the following dates are 18 Feb 1997, the 20th of july and 4 days from today.";
    long pre = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = getStanford(text, 1508745558);
    long post = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = post-pre;

    System.out.println(diff);
    System.out.println(map);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and days of sore black eyes. Here is where the problem is:

- Stanford "**parse**" model whether **PCFG** or **SRparser** both are CPU killers. You will never be able to scale. At best i was doing 70 docs/second. This is with 15 threads that i was able to manage on tomcat. The docs where being consumed from RabbitMQ. Machine Intel Xeon 8Core VM with 15 GB RAM. The CPU was always 90%.
- So if you want to do **NER**,**sentiment**,**sutime**. Its better to use separate libraries and not use stanford for all 3. For NER you can use **NERClassifierCombiner** from stanford. For sentiment you can use **weka**. For extracting dates you can use **natty**.
- Now we are able to do **2,000 docs/second**.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command on your example text:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,sentiment -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz  -file example-1.txt -outputFormat text -ner.nthreads 4 -parse.nthreads 4
```

And I got this timing information:

```
Annotation pipeline timing information:
TokenizerAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
WordsToSentencesAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
POSTaggerAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
MorphaAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
NERCombinerAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
ParserAnnotator: 0.2 sec.
SentimentAnnotator: 0.0 sec.
TOTAL: 0.4 sec. for 39 tokens at 105.1 tokens/sec.
Pipeline setup: 14.8 sec.
Total time for StanfordCoreNLP pipeline: 15.2 sec.
```

I see `0.4 sec` for the processing time.

1.) Make sure you don't rebuild the pipeline each time.  It appears your code is not rebuilding the pipeline in the main() method

2.) My command uses multi-threading for `ner` and `parse`.  Note that I am also using the shift-reduce parser which is substantially faster than the default parser.

3.) All of the pipeline settings can be set in Java API code by assigning them to the Properties object you use to build the pipeline.  Here is exhaustive documentation for using the Java API (you will have to convert this into Scala):

Java API: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

command line: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

4.) You don't need to build a separate NERClassifierCombiner, you can use the `ner` annotator, which will also run SUTime.

5.) I should note the time will be dominated by the parser.  You can choose not to parse really long sentences with `-parse.maxlen N` and set N to whatever token length you'd like.

6.) If you want to get character offsets for full entity mentions, make sure to add the `entitymentions` annotator to the end of the annotators list.  Each sentence has a list of entity mentions in it.  Each entity mention is a CoreMap.  You can get access to the begin and end character offsets of the entity mention with this code:

```
    List<CoreMap> mentions = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class);
    for (CoreMap mention : mentions) {
        int docCharBegin = mention.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class);
        int docCharEnd = mention.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation.class);
    }
```

Please let me know if you have any questions about converting this into Scala code.

Comment: How can i use NamedEntityTagAnnotation with classifyToCharacterOffsets ? I am having trouble merging similar entities together.

Comment: Now its taking 2096 milliseconds overall and 1724 seconds seem to be taken up by one line alone -> Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(s); I am using the following annotations now: props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,sentiment,sutime,entity‌​mentions");


I did run it with jvisualvm and it still seems to be using ExhaustivePCFGParser. It is taking most of the self time. 

This is even though i have used 

props.setProperty("-parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");

What is going on ?

Comment: "parse.model" not "-parse.model"

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL

Comment: If i add - in the starting its working. 
Also props.setProperty("parse.buildgraphs", "false"); seems to be giving me a half second boost. I hope NER, Sentiment and SUTIME will not be affected by this configuration.

Comment: You need the English models jar to use the shift-reduce parser, available here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Comment: I have added the srparser and updated configuration and SR Parser is taking more time than PCFG parser. Almost twice more time.

Comment: How much RAM are you allocating

Comment: You will definitely need to have a limit on sentence length for parsing.

Comment: String text ="Amid a long series of unexecuted orders of Napoleon's one series, for the campaign of 1812, was carried out--not because those orders differed in any way from the other, unexecuted orders but because they coincided with the course of events that led the French army into Russia.";

Comment: Try this sentence: 

String text ="Amid a long series of unexecuted orders of Napoleon's one series, for the campaign of 1812, was carried out--not because those orders differed in any way from the other, unexecuted orders but because they coincided with the course of events that led the French army into Russia.";

!! RAM increased !!
VM Arguments: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms4016m -Xmx6144m

PCFG parser taking : 2.8 seconds
SRParser taking : 2.9 seconds(Sometimes taking 16 seconds as well)

Can u tell me in what case SRParser will be faster than PCFG because so far i hav not seen it.

Comment: When I ran on your example sentence, I got 0.3 seconds for the SR parser, and 0.9 seconds for the regular parser.  You might want to start on one of your worker nodes and run the java command I provided above and run it again deleting the option for using the SR parser model.  Then you can verify the issue is with Scala integration.  You should see 0.3 vs. 0.9 for the parser.

Comment: PCFG parser is working marginally faster than SR parser if i use 

props.setProperty("parse.buildgraphs", "false");

Can you confirm this at your end also ?

Comment: props.setProperty("parse.model", "classifiers/englishSR.ser.gz");

Do i need to do anything else to enable SR parser ?

SR parser is not working as your saying it should work.